# specifc links to listview in (android studio)

Tags: java, android, listview

I am working on a personal project for pescatarian diet users and can't seem to get my listview working w/ links working. I can open my list view fine and look at my list. But when i try to clicking on an individual link it doesnt prompt me to go to any url. I included both my xml and main java code. Any suggestions or helpful tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import static android.R.attr.id;

public class Activity3 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_3);
        String[] foods = {"Bang Bang Shrimp", "Moroccan Fish Skewers", "Broiled Salmon Herbed Couscous", "Chilean Sea Bass", "Blackened Fish Tacos", "Argentinian Style Cod"};

        ListAdapter recipeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, foods);
        ListView recipeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.recipeListView);
        recipeListView.setAdapter(recipeAdapter);


    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://thegirlonbloor.com/bang-bang-shrimp-bibimbap-noodle-bowls/" )));
                break;

            case 1:
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://jellytoastblog.com/moroccan-fish-skewers/" )));
                break;

            case 2:
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.mykitchenlove.com/15-minute-dinner-broiled-salmon-herbed-couscous-salad/" )));
                break;

            case 3:
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://kitchenswagger.com/recipes/blackened-fish-tacos-recipe/" )));
                break;

            case 4:
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://thatovenfeelin.com/chilean-sea-bass-bag-en-papillote/" )));
                break;

            case 5:
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.twoofakindcooks.com/argentinian-style-cod-sauteed-vegetables/" )));
                break;



}}}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/recipeListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/activity_3"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@+id/activity_3"
        android:clickable="true"

         />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your not applied `setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: @DCaldwell apply listener on listview .check my answer

Comment: Use customized adapter with a POJO class for foods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
String[] foods = {"Bang Bang Shrimp", "Moroccan Fish Skewers", "Broiled Salmon Herbed Couscous", "Chilean Sea Bass", "Blackened Fish Tacos", "Argentinian Style Cod"};

ListAdapter recipeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, foods);
ListView recipeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.recipeListView);
recipeListView.setAdapter(recipeAdapter);
recipeListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://thegirlonbloor.com/bang-bang-shrimp-bibimbap-noodle-bowls/")));
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://jellytoastblog.com/moroccan-fish-skewers/")));
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.mykitchenlove.com/15-minute-dinner-broiled-salmon-herbed-couscous-salad/")));
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://kitchenswagger.com/recipes/blackened-fish-tacos-recipe/")));
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://thatovenfeelin.com/chilean-sea-bass-bag-en-papillote/")));
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.twoofakindcooks.com/argentinian-style-cod-sauteed-vegetables/")));
                        break;


                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this code below.

```
    Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("YOUR_URL");
    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
    startActivity(launchBrowser);
```